# Making sense of the Audit table in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I'm attempting to extract all the Merged records out of CRM and I see in the "Audit History" page of a Contact record the following:

[image]

If I click on it, I get the following:

[image]

And if I profile the code to see what SQL runs, it executes the following:

```
exec sp_executesql N'select 
"audit0".AuditId as "auditid"
, "audit0".AttributeMask as "attributemask"
, "audit0".ChangeData as "changedata"
, "audit0".CreatedOn as "createdon"
, "audit0".Action as "action"
, "audit0".Operation as "operation"
, "audit0".CallingUserId as "callinguserid"
, "audit0".UserId as "userid"
, "audit0".ObjectId as "objectid"
, "audit0".ObjectTypeCode as "objecttypecode"
, "audit0".CallingUserIdName as "callinguseridname"
, "audit0".UserIdName as "useridname"
, "audit0".ObjectIdName as "objectidname" 
from
 Audit as "audit0" 
where
 ("audit0".AuditId = @AuditId0)',N'@AuditId0 uniqueidentifier',
 @AuditId0='7FE1B120-87EC-E811-8BE0-005056B12EA2'
```

with the results shown as:

[image]

Does anyone know how I get the Yes record that it was actually merged? I can't make sense of the results on how they get displayed as Old Value v New  Value.

Comment: Maybe this blog post will give you some hints http://a33ik.blogspot.com/2011/11/crm-2011-reports-on-data-auditing.html?m=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the *Save* button on the record in CRM there's **one** audit row created in SQL, which describes all the changes made by this save. Only the `old values` are stored in SQL.
So how to get `new values`?
You can sort *audit* query by *createdon* ascending and for every row the `new value` is the next's row `old value`. To get the final `new value` you should join *audit* table with the *contact* table and get the *Merged* field value from the *contact* table.